# Shower fixture close to above lighting fixture

Tags: electrical, shower

What is the golden rule to a canned light fixture close to the shower head.

With all the splashing from washing hair it looks really close.  I think I am going to have contractor just close it up.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You may want to include a picture and some measurements to help people get a handle on the situation. You may also want to include your locale, as building codes vary based on location. In general, though, unless the house is really old and hasn't been touched in years, it's _probably_ built to code meaning that _theoretically_ there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

The fixture needs to be **rated for Wet locations** and should be **protected by a GFCI.**